# Where to get latest SVN bindings against Apache 2.2?

Tags: svn, apache, apache2, binding, apache2.2

Auld lang syne, it was possible to download pre-compiled bindings (binaries) of SVN against Apache 2.x on [subversion.tigris.org](http://subversion.tigris.org/)

Where now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays links can be found starting from [here](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html). This usually, but not always, leads you to [collab.net downloads](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/) which requires creation of a free account.

UPDATE: Specifically at Collab.net you will want "**CollabNet Subversion Server and Client v1.6.12** for (platform of your choice)".

Since Collab.net came out with "Subversion Edge", it seems you need to go to "see [previous collab.net releases](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/svn1.5.html)" to find these.

Comment: Thanks! But what file on Collab is for Apache?

Comment: I believe all "Server and Client" releases at collab.net should have the apache modules included. svn 1.6.x will be for Apache 2.2.x, where as svn 1.5.x will be for Apache 2.0.x